# What should you do differently when designing websites for an embedded web server

Tags: website-design, web-hosting, server, design

When *designing* a website to be accessed from an embedded webserver such as [KLone](http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/), what do you need to do differently compared to a 'standard' web server. I'm talking about considerations at the front end design stage, before the actual building and coding up.

For example, typically in such situations, memory size is a premium, so I guess larger images are out, and maybe more attention should be focused on achieving a good look and feel using CSS/Javascript rather than bitmap images.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a CDN then images wouldn't matter, you could also serve your CSS from there so it wouldn't matter and JavaScript gets ran in the browser so there would be no memory overheads there.

I think the biggest issue you could face is accepting data from forms, make sure that people can't overload any forms with so much information that it make make it difficult for KLone to deal with.